# Regex for 1 or more letters numbers, and exactly one special char

Tags: regex, bash

I need help with a Regex for 1  or more lowercase letters, 1 or more uppercase letters , 1  or more digits, and exactly 1 special character.

I wrote this so far:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\@\#\^])[a-zA-Z0-9\@\#\^]*$
```

It gets more than one special character.
By the way I'm using grep -P, and I'm testing my regex's with http://regexr.com/ first.

I forgot to mention that the characters should be in any order.

Comment: Bash regexes don't implement lookahead assertions.

Comment: ^ i know im using grep -P so i can use lookaheads.

Comment: then don't say you are using bash. Say you are using `grep -P` and avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

separate your special characters to a different character class that only matches once:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\@\#\^][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
#NOTES:                       ^you dont need to do a look ahead for the special char since you explicitly match only 1

 (?=...) ...                 ) signifies lookaheads: they each check that there is at least
one number, lowercase, and uppercase letter in the following match 
                               [a-zA-Z0-9]* matches 0 or more of those for as long as possible
                                           [\@\#\^] matches exactly one of these characters
                                                    [a-zA-Z0-9]* matches any of the remaining characters
```

this works better than the original because it ensures that one, and only one, special character is matched

Comment: @RNar, It would be very nice and quite helpful if you could break down the RegEx with an explanation of how it works.